# Polynomial complex equation with conjugates

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-numbers, algebraic-curves

I am looking for bibliographical resources where I can read about polynomial equation with conjugates of the following form
$$\sum_{k+l\leq n}a_{k,l}z^k\overline{z}^l=0$$

For example for $n=2$

$$a_{0,2}\overline{z}^2+a_{2,0}z^2+a_{1,1}z\overline{z}+a_{0,1}\overline{z}+a_{1,0}z+a_{0,0}=0$$

I have found it interesting because the set of solutions cannot be trivially described as in the case without conjugates.

Isn't it a good research topic for undergraduate dissertation?

Comment: Just a comment on the "*the set of solutions cannot be trivially described as in the case without conjugates*" part, but you can eliminate $\bar z$ between $P(z,\bar z) = 0$ and $\bar P(\bar z, z) = 0$ to get an algebraic equation in $z$ alone.

Comment: @dxiv can you be more specific? I don't understand. Take for example $$z^2=\overline{z}^2$$ After replacing $z$ with $\overline{z}$ you obtain the same equation.

Comment: Same with just $z = \bar z$. Those are limit cases where the solution set is not discrete, and you would need to treat them separately in your dissertation. Generally speaking, however, $P(z,\bar z)=0$ will have finitely many solutions, which you can find as suggested in my comment, using e.g. polynomial resultants.

Comment: Just a comment, if you let $\mathbf{z} = [1,z,\dots,z^n]^T$ then the equation you wrote is equivalent to the equation $\mathbf{z}^H\mathbf{A}\mathbf{z}=0$ where $H$ denotes the hermitian transpose. So we can define an inner product $\langle\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}\rangle$ by $\mathbf{x}^H\mathbf{A}\mathbf{y}$ and you are essentially looking for when $\langle\mathbf{z},\mathbf{z}\rangle=0$. You might want to Google about Hilbert spaces, positive-definiteness, quadratic forms, etc. (But I'm not sure how it relates to the specific case when the entries of $\mathbf{z}$ are all powers of $z$ here.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. "*Polynomial and Rational Inequalities*" by Peter Borwein and Tamas Erdelyi. This book has a chapter on complex conjugate polynomials, including examples similar to the one you provided.
2. "*A Course in Complex Analysis and Riemann Surfaces*" by Wilhelm Schlag. This book includes a chapter on polynomial equations, including equations with conjugates.
3. "*Algebraic Numbers and Algebraic Functions*" by Paul J. McCarthy. This book includes a section on complex conjugate polynomials.
4. "*Topics in Algebraic and Analytic Geometry*" by Maria Aparecida Soares Ruas and Jorge Vitório Pereira. This book includes a chapter on algebraic curves, which discusses polynomial equations with conjugates.